# How does one deal with 2 waves to view their beats graphically?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference

Two tuning forks have frequencies of 480 Hz and 512 Hz respectively.

The beat frequency should be the difference, which is 32 Hz.

Now I want to see this graphically.

I modelled these two waves as sine waves.

$$W_1 = \sin{\frac{2\pi x}{480}}$$ and $$W_2 = \sin{\frac{2 \pi x}{512}}$$

When I graphed these two waves I got what I expected, i.e. two waves with frequencies of 480 Hz and 512 Hz respectively.

Now I want to view their beats.

What way do I combine $W_1$ and $W_2$ to see the resulting beats?

i.e. I want to see the number 32 emerge from the graph by combining $W_1$ and $W_2$ somehow.
I've tried basic addition, subtraction, multiplication and division but to no success.

When I do add these two waves together I get a pattern which has a frequency equal to the lowest common multiple of 480 and 512 (i.e. 7680 Hz)

What is this frequency called or what does it represent ?

I thought it was the beat frequency.

Comment: Are you sure $W_1$ and $W_2$ do have the frequencies you're saying? I'd rather say 480 and 512 are their *periods* in $x$. What exactly did you plot? How did you obtain the plot?

Comment: You are right. I inputted those values as periods instead of frequencies. I have since plotted $\sin(960 \pi x)$ and $\sin(1024 \pi x)$ and the resulting superposition does in fact have a frequency of 32 Hz. Problem solved.